# Erlang: unable to send form parameters in the post request

Tags: python, erlang

I have the following code in my erlang script. However on executing, I get the request in the server, but I am not able to get the form parameters.

```
application:start(inets),                                                                                                                                                                  
Method = post,                                                                                                                                                                             
URL = "http://servername/cgi-bin/serverscript.py",                                                                                                                                     
Header = [],                                                                                                                                                                               
Type = "multipart/form-data",                                                                                                                                                              
Body = "{\"text\":\"data\"}",                                                                                                                                                            
HTTPOptions = [],                                                                                                                                                                          
Options = [],                                                                                                                                                                              
httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options).
```

Following is the code I am usign to fetch the Form params in python:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Comment: I have tried "application/json" value for the variable "Type".

Comment: Did it help? Multipart requires additional boundary parameter and specific body structure.

Comment: The change mentioned as answer helped me. application/json didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
application:start(inets),                                                                                                                                                                  
Method = post,                                                                                                                                                                             
URL = "http://servername/cgi-bin/serverscript.py",                                                                                                                                     
Header = [],                                                                                                                                                                               
Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",                                                                                                                                                
N = string:concat("from=", "fromemail"),                                                                                                                                        
P = string:concat("to=", "toemail"),                                                                                                                                          
Body = string:join([N, P], "&"),                                                                                                                                                           
HTTPOptions = [],                                                                                                                                                                          
Options = [],                                                                                                                                                                              
httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options).
```